# Customizing Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erl

I am creating a XMPP chat service for this I'm using ejabberd.

Features that i want to implement are

Add custom fields like phone number , email at the time of registration.I need help regarding which lines should i edit in mod_register to accept more fields at the time of Registration.

Eliminate the default vcard module with a custom profile module which can act like the same but serve images as url like avatar.example.org/getavatar.php?username=myusername@example.com

Am new to Erlang so am little confused about how to start with developing these modules or customizing the built in modules of Ejabberd so that they can serve these features.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to have fundamental skill in the operating environment to be able to solve problems in it. If someone gave you a broken automobile, do you think that you could ask a question on how to make it work without having a good idea of how internal combustion engines work in the first place? What if it wasn't anything to do with the engine at all?

I am not trying to be snarky, but you're going to have to invest more time in understanding things, ask specific questions that include what you've tried, and then you might make some progress with the answers people provide.

Comment: Thanks Brian, Actually am new to Erlang so just don't know where to start.

Comment: If it were me, I would get comfortable with building and debugging the software from source, then look through the source a big to understand what is possible. Especially take a look at modules written by others and try to make modifications to them and deploy them to a running server. Once you have that in hand, the mods you need to make will come naturally and you'll have specific questions when they don't work. Hope that helps!

Comment: If i register user by a php script and adding user pwd email in mysql table directly will it works ? or i need to call it through register module only and save all other info directly in user table